# Server-side access to Client Browser's Latitude/Longitude using Django

Tags: javascript, django, json, geolocation, mobile-safari

So i am writing a little app that compares a user's position against a database on web-based server written
using Django and performs some functions with it.

Accessing the browser's geolocation data (in supported browsers ) is [fairly trivial using JavaScript](http://mapscripting.com/how-to-use-geolocation-in-mobile-safari). But what is the best way to allow
the Django server to access the longitude and latitude variables? Is it best to wrap them up as a JSON object and 
send to the server via POST? Or is there some easier (Geo)Django-based way to access the *Navigator.geolocation* browser
object.

Please forgive a newbie a question like this, but my Google-Fuing only seems to find ways to insert variables into
JavaScript via template tag, whereas I need it to work the other way!

Any advice or code snippets greatly appreciated. Feel free to talk to me like I am an idiot.

Answer (score 3):

You will indeed need to POST your location data to a Django view.

If all you need is simple distance calculations, take a look at [Geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/).

If you want to interact with the ORM and filter/search based on location, you'll want to look at [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/).

Answer (score 1):

`Navigator.geolocation` is only available on the client side. You'll have to send the data back to the server using Javascript, such as via a POST (as you surmised).